# C# How does a child class member find out which index in a parent list it comes from?

Tags: c#, class

Let's say I have a class

```
public class member{
   int Num;
}

public class C1
{
    List<member> Nums=new List<member>();
    public C1
    {
       Nums.Add(66);
       Nums.Add(24);
       Nums.Add(32);
       Nums.Add(34);
    } 
}
```

Let's say I have access to an object of type member and it is a child to C1. Let's say it's the one with Num=32. How can I, having that object find out that 32 is the 3rd member in list Nums? That is without having the actual variable Nums! All I have is an object of type member.

I have a workaround...I can add another int into class member and as I add members I can index it. For example...

```
public class member{
   int Num;
   int Order;
}

public class C1
{
    List<member> Nums=new List<member>();
    public C1
    {
       Nums.Add(66,1);
       Nums.Add(24,2);
       Nums.Add(32,3);
       Nums.Add(34,4);
    } 
}
```

Now if I have an object of type member I will know where in the Nums list it exists.

Anyhow...if there is a better way...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this actually work in C# `Nums.Add(24);` without giving an error? There isn't even a getter or setter in the member class. (Just curious)

Comment: Is this pseudocode? Because as written, this code won't compile.

Comment: Sorry yes pseudo code...I didn't compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do have access to the `Nums` while creating `member` and you can modify `member` the easy way would be to add a field to `member` that would keep reference to `Nums`.

```
public class member
    {
        int Num;
        private readonly List<member> _parrentList;

        public member(List<member> parrentList)
        {
            _parrentList = parrentList;
        }

        public int IndexOnParentList => _parrentList.IndexOf(this);
    }
```

Keeping index as a int would require more maintenance as the value would have to be updated when the `Nums` gets reordered or items get added/removed.